# text box should display,if user enters two means two text box should display for get the name and one text box should display some texts

Tags: angular

Based on the user input, the text box should display on the screen. For example, if the user enters two is two means two text box should display for get the user name and one text box should display for some texts. That text box should display in right of the first text box,I have done it, but I am unable to store the value.If any one can provide a simpler code , And able to store the values as well as.

Here is my code:

```
    No entered by user: <input type ="text" (keyup)= 

    "ValueEntered($event.target.value)</td>

    <ng-template ngFor [ngForOf]="times(x)">

name:<input type="text" value=" ">

</ng-template>

<ng-template ngFor [ngForOf]="times(x-1)">

textbox:<input type="text" value=" ">   
</ng-template>

enter code here`

ValueEntered(event)
  {
      this.x=event;
  console.log('input value',event);
  }

function times(x) {
  return {
    [Symbol.iterator]: function* () {
      for (let i = 0; i < x; i++, yield) {
      }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to get the value? For that, you should depend on an iterating variable . I modified your HTML and ts code to incorperate the iterating varaible i

```
<input type ="text"  (keyup)= "ValueEntered($event.target.value)" >

<ng-template ngFor [ngForOf]="times(x)" let-i="index">
name:<input type="text" value=" " [(ngModel)]='datasets1[i]' (change)='checkval(i)'>

</ng-template>

 <ng-template ngFor [ngForOf]="times(x-1)" let-i="index">

textbox:<input type="text"  value=" " [(ngModel)]='datasets2[i]'>   
</ng-template
```

In the ts file, I defined two arrays to store the data dataset1 and dataset2

```
 datasets1 = [];
 datasets2 = [];
ValueEntered(event)
{
  this.x = event;
  console.log('input value',event);
 }
  checkval(i){
 console.log(this.datasets1[i])
 }
 times(x) {
 return {
 [Symbol.iterator]: function* () {
  for (let i = 0; i < x; i++, yield) {
   }}

}
}
```

Note that [(ngModel)] is a two way binding